# How to access the value of baseURL in Cypress

Tags: javascript, global-variables, cypress

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and have been using Cypress to automate some regression tests. The test I writing currently is meant to verify link's text and href in a header and footer.

The issue I am having is that these tests need to be run across various environments and I cannot seem to access the baseUrl property set in the cypress.json in order to set the domain in my assertion.

In the script that follows it is the line `cy.get("a").should("have.attr", "href", baseUrl + footerLink.link)`:

```js
    it.only("translates the content info section", () => {
      cy.wrap(orbitData).each(service => {
        cy.visit(service.name);
        cy.get("#orb-contentinfo > div > ul > li").each(($li, index) => {
          let footerLink = service.links[index]
          cy.wrap($li).should("have.text", footerLink.linkText)
          .within(($li) => {
            cy.get("a").should("have.attr", "href", baseUrl + footerLink.link)
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

So far I have tried a number of things, I'm a bit embarrassed to list them all, I'm new to this so they're probably insane and definitely just guesses; amongst them were `Cypress.env('CYPRESS_baseUrl')` and `Cypress.baseUrl`. Each time it just comes back as `undefined`.

Or, if I'm attacking this in completely the wrong way any guidance on a better way would be appreciated. I'd be grateful for any help or guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can use the [`Cypress.config()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Syntax) command.

To get `baseUrl` value use `Cypress.config().baseUrl` or `Cypress.config('baseUrl')`.

Answer (score 12):

`cy.visit('/')` will visit the baseUrl if you have it defined in your Cypress e2e config. ([Source](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Syntax))

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, cy.visit('') will also work btw.

Comment: Cypress says: "Cypress no longer supports cypress.json, please remove it from your project."

Comment: So I added to cypress.config.js inside of e2e and it worked

Comment: I updated my answer. Indeed, cypress.json has been deprecated, you should now add it inside the e2e object inside cypress.config.ts|js

Answer (score -2):

Using Cypress 7.7, I found that `Cypress.env('baseUrl')` worked.